# Storing MyClass values in List

Tags: c++-cli, generic-collections

I am completely new to C++\CLI and I have the following problem: I have a class called, for example, MyClass, a few values of which I need to store in memory. I have decided to use List, because it is the most familiar to me, since I was using C# for a long time. So here goes the code:

```
//Header File
ref class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(void);
private:
    System::Collections::Generic::List<MyClass^> values;
};
//CPP file
MyClass::MyClass(void){
this->values=gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<MyClass^>();
}
```

The compiler keeps on saying that there's an error [C2582](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983787%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). But if there's no assignment operator, then how should I initialize the List?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values` should not be a `List<...^>`, but a `List<...^>^`.  You want to assign a reference, not to create another clone of the list.